# TypeError: string indices must be integers in pandas_datareader.DataReader

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get facebook stock prices with pandas_datareader but it gives me this error. can anyone help me out?

```py
company = 'FB'

start = dt.datetime(2012, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()

data = pdr.DataReader(company, 'yahoo', start, end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like yahoo made changes to their API:

related git: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/952

One way can be:

```
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download(company, start , end)
```

`yf.download` also returns a dataframe.